# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm is not triggering after reaching threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have configure aws monitoring perl script for disk and memory related matrics. 
I did set a alarm which notify me if diskspace utilization is more than 50%.

Please take a look to alarm state below. 
[image]

below is my cloudformation template alarm resource section.

```
#--------------------
# DiskSpace Alarms
#--------------------
    {{ component_name }}DiskBasedAlarm:
      Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
      Properties:
        AlarmDescription: "ASG Alarm if disk space utilization is more than 50% for more than 10 minutes."
        Namespace: System/Linux
        EvaluationPeriods: 10
        Period: 60
        ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
        Statistic: Average
        Threshold: 50
        Unit: Percent
        TreatMissingData: ignore
        MetricName: DiskSpaceUtilization
        Dimensions:
          -
            Name: AutoScalingGroupName
            Value:
              Ref: WebASG
          -
            Name: MountPath
            Value: /
          -
            Name: Filesystem
            Value: /dev/nvme0n1p1
        AlarmActions:
          -
            Ref: CustomAlarmsNotifyTopic
```

Its been 3 - 4 hours but alarm is still in OK state. I have no idea why it is happening. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alarm is set to average, change it to the maximum to enable trigger.

```
Statistic: Maximum
```